Using Invoke-sqlcmd occasionally outputs a blank csv file
I'm fairly new to using powershell so bear with me. My goal is to query a database over our network and save the file output of the query as a csv on the local machine. The query works as intended but will occasionally output a blank csv file with no data in it. I'll post my script below. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
Invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Server -Database $Database -Username $username -Password $password -Query "SELECT * FROM $Table WHERE EventTimeStamp >= DATEADD(HH, -2, GETDATE());" | export-csv -path "$Path_$(Get-Date -Format yyyyMMddHHmmss).csv"

I've tried the above script and it works as expected but sometimes outputs a blank csv file.

Whenever your query happens to return no rows, Export-Csv will create an empty file (0 bytes).

Thanks for the reply. The query should definitely be returning something. This is a manufacturing environment that is constantly putting data into the table. If I'm watching and notice that it creates an empty file and run it again then it will have the data in it that I'm trying to get. Just trying to understand why it returns an empty file intermittently.

You'll need to investigate why the query sometimes produces no results and decide whether that's legitimate or not; with the information given, I don't think anyone can help you with that. (I doubt that there's a problem with Export-Csv: when it does receive input, it does produce non-empty files). If the query intermittently not producing results is legitimate and you want to avoid creating a CSV file in that case, either collect the query results first and test for .Count -eq 0 or delete the file after the fact if its size is 0 bytes.
